# Use piped stdin as argument to next command

Tags: shell, command-line, arguments

How do I use the output of a command as a parameter in another command? My specific example is that I want to get the *PID* of a process using `pgrep` and pass it to the `-p` option of `lsof`.

I've tried things like the following:

- `pgrep myprocess | lsof -p /dev/stdin`
- `pgrep myprocess | lsof -p -`

I know you can do it like this:

`pid=$(pgrep myprocess) && lsof -p "$pid"`

But there has to be a better way to do it. Perhaps `xargs` or something? I haven't been able to find something clean, so I'd appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Comment: `lsof -p "$(pgrep myprocess)"`

Comment: That's pretty good, but just wondering if there is a way which preserves the order of operations as you would imagine they should flow. Consider "we get the pid of the process, then use it in lsof".

Comment: isn't `xargs` created for such purpose? `pgrep myprocess | xargs lsof -p `

Comment: lsof -p \`pgrep myprocess\` (one character less) :P

Comment: surrounding commands with backquotes (\`\`) rather than with the `$()` construct would work for `csh`, and therefore for `tcsh`, which is the default shell in `freebsd`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assuming that `pgrep` may return multiple PIDs:

```
$ pgrep mycommand | xargs -n 1 lsof -p
```

This will, for each PID, run `lsof -p` with the PID appended.